# I try to get props to update a field but it not works (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, components, react-props

I am trying to bring the props of my component, however when I open the edit modal it only brings the data of my first object. I want to bring them to EditForm so that I can update a field, but without the id and other data I can't do it.

When I click on the edit button it brings me the data correctly, it prints it in the console, it prints the data that corresponds to each user, but when passing it through props it only takes the data of the first user. When I open my Edit modal it pastes the data of the first user only, and not those of each user that the button corresponds

```
EditForm.js:

import React, { Component } from 'react'

export class PatchForm extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            id: props.id,
            name: props.name,
            lastName: props.lastName,
            age: props.age,
            email: props.email,
            salary: props.salary,
            company: props.company,
            image: props.image
        }
    }


    changeHandler = e => {
        this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value})
    }


    render(){
        const { name, lastName, age, email, salary, company, image} = this.state
        return(
            <div className="modal fade" id="editModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div className="modal-dialog" role="document">
                    <div className="modal-content">
                        <div className="modal-header">
                            <h5 className="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">New message</h5>
                            <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div className="modal-body">
                            <form>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                    <label className="col-form-label">Name:</label>
                                    <input type="text" className="form-control" name="name" value={name} onChange={this.changeHandler}></input>
                                </div>
                                <div className="form-group">
                                    <label className="col-form-label">Last name:</label>
                                    <input type="text" className="form-control" name="lastName" value={lastName} onChange={this.changeHandler}></input>
                                </div>
                                <div className="form-group">
                                    <label className="col-form-label">Age:</label>
                                    <input type="number" className="form-control" name="age" value={age} onChange={this.changeHandler}></input>
                                </div>
                                <div className="form-group">
                                    <label className="col-form-label">Email:</label>
                                    <input type="email" className="form-control" name="email" value={email} onChange={this.changeHandler}></input>
                                </div>
                                <div className="form-group">
                                    <label className="col-form-label">Salary (MXNgit):</label>
                                    <input type="number" className="form-control" name="salary" value={salary} onChange={this.changeHandler}></input>
                                </div>
                                <div className="form-group">
                                    <label className="col-form-label">Company:</label>
                                    <input type="text" readOnly className="form-control" name="company" placeholder={company} onChange={this.changeHandler}></input>
                                </div>
                                <div className="form-group">
                                    <label className="col-form-label">URL img:</label>
                                    <input type="text" className="form-control" name="company" value={image} onChange={this.changeHandler}></input>
                                </div>
                                {/* <button type="submit">Submit</button> */}
                                <div className="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" className="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" id="submitButton" onClick={() => {
                                        window.location.reload()
                                    }}>Save changes</button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }

}

export default PatchForm
```

Table.jsx:

```
import React from 'react'
import PostForm from './PostForm'
import EditForm from './EditForm'


const EmployeesTable = () => {

    // Estados
    const [employee, setEmployee] = React.useState([])
    const [currency, setCurrency] = React.useState(true)

    // Ejecutamos la función en solo una ocasión con useEffect
    React.useEffect( () => {
        obtenerDatos()
    }, [])

    // Obtenemos los datos de los empleados
    const obtenerDatos = async () => {
        const data = await fetch('http://localhost:8080')
        const employeesObject = await data.json()
        const {employees} = employeesObject.data
        setEmployee(employees)
    }

    // Formato de moneda
    let formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
        style: 'currency',
        currency: 'MXN',
    });

    let formatterUSD = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
        style: 'currency',
        currency: 'USD',
    });

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="col-12 text-center">
                <div className="col-12 col-lg-6 offset-lg-3">
                    {/* Condicional para cambiar entre false and true */}
                    <button className="btn m-2 btn-outline-success" onClick={() => setCurrency(!currency)}>Change Currency</button>
                    <button type="button" className=" m-2 btn btn-outline-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#createModal">Create Employee</button>
                </div>
                
                <table className="table table-dark text-center col-12 col-lg-6 offset-lg-3">
                    <thead className="thead-dark">
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">Total employees</th>
                            <th scope="col">Currency</th>

                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row">{employee.length}</th>
                            <th>{ currency ? "MXN" : "USD" }</th>
                        </tr>

                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>


            {/* Form para creación de empleados */}
            <PostForm />

            <div className="table-wrapper-scroll-y my-custom-scrollbar">
                <table className="table table-hover table-striped col-12">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>#</th>
                            <th>Avatar</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Last name</th>
                            <th>Age</th>
                            <th>Email</th>
                            <th>Salary {currency ? 'MXN' : 'USD'}</th>
                            <th>Company</th>
                            <th>Actions</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody className="col-6">
                    {
                        // Iteramos para obtener los datos de cada empleado e imprimirlos en el DOM
                        employee.map((item, index) => {
                            return (
                                <tr key={item._id}>
                                    <th>{index + 1}</th>
                                    <td>
                                        <img className="img-size" src={item.image} alt="img"/>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>{item.name}</td>
                                    <td>{item.lastName}</td>
                                    <td>{item.age}</td>
                                    <td>{item.email}</td>
                                    {/* Condicional para cambiar clase de color */}
                                    <td className={ item.salary > 10000 ? "green text-right" : "red text-right"} >{ currency ? formatter.format(item.salary) : formatterUSD.format(item.salary * 21.5)}</td>
                                    <td >{item.company}</td>

                                    <td>
                                        <EditForm 
                                            id={item._id}
                                            name={item.name}
                                            lastName={item.lastName}
                                            age={item.age}
                                            email={item.email}
                                            salary={item.salary}
                                            company={item.company}
                                            image={item.image}
                                        />
                                        <i className="fas fa-edit cursor-pointer" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal" onClick={()=> {console.log(item._id)}}></i>
                                    </td>
                                    
                                </tr>
                            )
                        })
                    }
                    </tbody>
                    
                </table>
            </div>

            

            
        </div>
    )
        
}

export default EmployeesTable;
```

Comment: How are you opening `EditForm`? I did not find any react code for that.

Comment: Before to export EmployeesTable, in Table,jsx. In the ”edit” icon.

Comment: I think the modal isn't getting re-rendered when you click the button, so it only has the first/initial state. You maybe need to also trigger a change for the modal- it needs to share a state with the parent, like selectedEmployeeId or something, so that you can change it on click and cause it to pull in new data.